# What C preprocessor conditional should I use for OS X specific code?

Tags: c, macos, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

What C preprocessor conditional should I use for OS X specific code? I need to include a specific library if I am compiling for OS X or a different header if I am compiling for Linux.

I know there is `__APPLE__` but I don't know if that is a current conditional for OS X 10.x.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[This list of operating system macros](http://predef.sourceforge.net/preos.html#sec19)  says the presence of **both** `__APPLE__` and  `__MACH__` indicate OSX.

Also confirmed at line 18 of part of  [the source for `fdisk`](http://bitbucket.org/skypher/fdisk/src/9554485fdadb/m4/gnulib-common.m4).

Answer (score 7):

`__APPLE__` will tell you you're compiling on an Apple platform. Unless you need to support MacOS versions before OS X, that should be good enough. Alternately, you could use `__APPLE__` and `__MACH__` to make sure you're compiling on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, it's `__APPLE__` :)

Comment: I believe this is for both MAC and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

This code example may help you -

```
if defined(__APPLE__)
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
  if (!defined(TARGET_OS_IPHONE) && !defined(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR))
 {
   //write your OSX specific code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

old style raw:

```
#ifdef WIN32
// windows.
#elif __APPLE__
// osx and ios.
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/) contains a list of all OS predefined macros.

For mac OSX both the `__APPLE__` && `__MACH__` need to be defined.