# Simmulate 'Insert'-key on mac with delphi firemonkey.

Tags: macos, delphi, insert, firemonkey

I have created win32 program that uses the shortcut 'Insert' a lot.
Now I am converting the program to Mac. I find that there is no default 'Ins' key on the keyboard. But on further [investigation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202676) I find that u can use the combination of fn+return.

Now Delphi does not catch the combination of these keys. But only the key events of the 'Return', the 'fn' is lost. But i have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777796/how-to-catch-the-fn-keys-on-laptop) that the 'fn' key changes the key send from the keyboard instead of sending a combination.

Is there a possibility to catch it when a user presses 'fn + return'.

Comment: What if the keyboard has no fn key?

Comment: It is still a shortcut. So there are always other ways to get to the functionality. I just want to keep my shortcuts the same for mac and windows. And I cannot change the windows shortcuts because of legacy users.

Comment: It might be more prudent to offer a different shortcut for Mac users in this case, so that they can access it without that key

Comment: +1 to what David said. What is the closest, most intuitive Mac equivalent to the 'Ins' key? Then do a preprocessor check in your program for Macs, examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529031/what-c-preprocessor-conditional-should-i-use-for-os-x-specific-code .

Comment: That's the C++ flavor of Delphi, so the Objective Pascal equivalent to that.

Comment: I use a Mac keyboard all the time, and I, too, would do what David says: offer a different, Mac-like shortcut. I don't know for what the `Ins` key is used in your Windows program, but I would look for a Mac alternative. E.g., In the Delphi IDE editor on the Mac, Ctrl+V toggles between insert and override mode, just like usually `Ins` does. Note that in that setup, copy is Cmd+V, not Ctrl+V.

Comment: FWIW, there is no need to change the Windows shortcuts. Just add appropriate shortcuts for the Mac. Windows does not have a Cmd key, so use that for key combinations.

Comment: Cmd is the Win key on a Windows keyboard. So it is probably better to only add those shortcuts on the Mac.

Comment: Thnx for all the advice guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fn+Enter will return KEY_PADENTER, but that will be translated by FMX to a simple return. You'd have to use RegisterKeyMapping / UnregisterKeyMapping in order to reassign that. But I hope you've already learnt from the comments that Fn+Enter is probably not a good idea for the Mac. So don't annoy your users with Windows shortcuts. Instead of telling them that they have to press Fn+Enter you could just as well tell them to use another shortcut.

Another trick is that the MacBook keyboard doesn't have a Delete key, so most Mac applications often use Backspace instead of Delete for the hotkeys. It is just faster than pressing the replacement Fn+Backspace. Also Mac users expect the Cmd key instead of Ctrl for most shortcuts.